# How do I find properties and fields for a type and then read them from a collection of that type?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

i have list of T and need to create a string joined by "\t" with several properties of this type.

```
string str = "1,2,3;2,3,4;4,5,6";
var arr = str
    .Split(';')
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        first = x[0],
        second = x[1],
        third = x[2]
    })
    .ToList();
```

now arr is:

```
Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<string, <>f__AnonymousType0#10<string, string, string>> { \{ first = "1", second = "2", third = "3" }, \{ first = "2", second = "3", third = "4" }, \{ first = "4", second = "5", third = "6" } }
```

now if i need to get

```
List<string>(3) { "1\t2\t3", "2\t3\t4", "4\t5\t6" }
```

i should do this

```
arr.Select(x => x.first + "\t" + x.second + "\t" + x.third).ToList();
```

i need extension method that allow me to do this

```
arr.Select(x => x.first, x.second, x.third).ToList();
```

and get same result.

i have extension method that join by tab all fields of object

```
public static IEnumerable<string> JoinByTab<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : class
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = list.FirstOrDefault().GetType().
        GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var listStr = list
        .Select(x => String.Join("\t", properties.Select(y => y.GetValue(x, null).ToString())));

    return listStr;
}
```

but often i need to specify fields.

Comment: why is an anonymous type required when you can easily make a model class ?

Comment: If it helps, you can replace `list.FirstOrDefault().GetType()` with `typeof(T)`.

Comment: When you say "anonymous type" do you mean `T`? That's a generic type, not an anonymous type. I'm not trying to nitpick. It's just that "anonymous type" means something specific and different, so people will be confused trying to figure out what the anonymous type is. (If I'm right then you can edit the question. It will help.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you are actually using an anonymous type. It's possible that I've answered entirely the wrong question. (In all fairness, I should get all of that clarification before answering the question, shouldn't I?) But it doesn't look like the anonymous type is an integral part of the question. It looks like you're trying to update the function to read both properties and fields, not just properties. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a bunch of lambdas to the join method, for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,
    string separator,
    params Func<T, string>[] properties) where T : class
{
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        yield return string.Join(separator, properties.Select(p => p(element)));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var result = arr.Join("\t", 
        x => x.first, 
        x => x.second, 
        x => x.third)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> but often i need to specify fields.

You need often to concatenate object fields with tab separator? You even have extension method for that? Wow, that's an interesting project.

You can simply create an array from your object and use regular string.Join

```
arr.Select(x => string.Join("\t", new[] { x.first, x.second, x.third }).ToList();
```

no extension method needed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the all of the `string` properties and fields from type `T`. Then for each item in a set of `T` you want to read all of those string properties and then join those strings. You're starting with a list of `T` and ending with a list of `string`.

This gets easier if you separate the part of the code that does the reflection (finds the properties and fields) from the part that reads the list of objects.

Since the properties and fields are the same for all the objects in the list (because they're all the same type) you're trying to discover the properties and fields once and then reuse them. That's good.

So the question is how to do that. Here's two ways.

The first takes the type (`T') and returns all of the public instance properties and fields that return`string`.`PropertyInfo`and`MemberInfo`both inherit from`MemberInfo`, so we're returning a set of`MemberInfo`.

```
public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetStringMembers<T>()
{
    var result = new List<MemberInfo>();
    result.AddRange(
            typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(string)));
    result.AddRange(
        typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof(string)));
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that now each item in the list can be a `PropertyInfo` or a `FieldInfo`, so when we try to get each value from each class instance we need to look at each member and see if it's a property or a field because it's a different method for reading each one. That's messy. (I know because I've written that exact code.)

A better approach would be creating a list of functions that take a `T` and return a string. Inside each function we could be checking a property or a field. That would look like this. I did it without LINQ to make it easier to read:

```
private static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetStringMemberFunctions<T>()
{
    var result = new List<Func<T, string>>();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        result.Add(item => (string)property.GetValue(item));
    }
    var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        result.Add(item => (string)field.GetValue(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

What we're returning is a list of `Func<T, string>`. That's a list of functions that take `T` and returns a `string`. Each one of those functions is checking either a property or a field. (Resharper can convert this to LINQ expressions for me, but I'm not posting it because it's harder to read so I don't think it helps.)

Now your original method doesn't contain all of that reflection. It lets another method handle that, and it looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> JoinByTab<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : class
{
    var functions = GetStringMemberFunctions<T>();

    var listStr = list
        .Select(x => String.Join("\t", functions.Select(function => function(x))));

    return listStr;
}
```

It's exactly the same except

- Instead of finding the properties using reflection, you're getting a list of functions from another method.
- Instead of reading each property you're invoking each method.

You could also go a step further. Instead of getting a list of functions and calling them all to build a list of strings, you could create a new function that combines them all. That one function would invoke all of the other functions and just return all of the strings.

```
public static Func<T, string[]> GetExtractStringValuesFunction<T>()
{
    var memberFunctions = GetStringMemberFunctions<T>();
    return item => memberFunctions.Select(function => function(item)).ToArray();
}

public static IEnumerable<string> JoinByTab<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : class
{
    var stringValuesFunction = GetExtractStringValuesFunction<T>();

    var listStr = list
        .Select(x => String.Join("\t", stringValuesFunction(x)));

    return listStr;
}
```

It calls `GetStringMemberFunctions` to get all of the functions for reading members and then combines them all into one `Func<T, string[]>`. Now we've got a single function that takes an instance of `T` and returns all of the strings from the properties and fields.

This is a smaller improvement just for illustration. If the previous version is easy to understand then this doesn't add a whole lot of benefit.

---

Side note:

Doing this to get the list of properties and fields isn't safe and could cause an exception:

```
list.FirstOrDefault().GetType()
```

All of the items in your list are of type `T`. But hypothetically any individual item in that list could also inherit from `T`. So what happens if the first item in the list is a type that inherits from `T` and has properties or fields that other objects in the list don't?

`GetType()` will return the *concrete* type of the object. It might be exactly `T`, but it might be some inherited type. You could create a list of properties and fields based on that type, but then get an exception because you try to read them from objects that don't have those properties or fields.

That's why, if you have a `List<T>` and you want to get the type, it's safer to use `typeof(T)`.

(The code in your question implies an assumption that all items in the list should be treated as the same type. If you wanted to actually account for different types that inherit from `T` and have different properties and fields that's possible, just a slightly bigger can of worms.)

Comment: Why would you return a list of functions returning string just to execute all of them right after instead of returning just a list of strings?

Comment: The reason we're creating functions is because at that step we're discovering the list of properties and fields. If the function did that reflection and then also returned the list of strings that would work. But it means we'd be repeating that reflection for every single item in the list, even though they're all the same type. That's what we're trying to avoid. Reflection isn't so expensive that we should avoid it at all costs, but it is expensive enough that I wouldn't want to do it over and over unnecessarily.

Comment: oh I didn't notice that you do it once for all objects in the list, makes sense. If you want some real optimization though try Expressions, it's even possible to runtime compile code that will do exactly x.First + "\t" + x.Second + "\t" + x.Third